# Text Align froalaEditor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, froala

I am using froalaEditor in my application, I am encountering an weird issue, As seen in the attached snapshot.

[image]

I am having an dropdown to align content, it is behaving as intended for **right** and **centre** alignment of content, but not for **left** alignment.

Fo Instance this is how the content looks when I select **right** **alignment**.

[image]

And this how rendered **DOM** looks like.

[image]

Similarly for **center** alignment.

[image]

**DOM** for **center**.

[image]

Now the weird things is this is how content looks like for **left** **alignment**.

[image]

And this is how **DOM** looks like.

[image]

Intended behaviour is to append `text-align: left;` to the `div` in the **DOM** as user has selected **left** alignment from the dropdown.

Don't know why it is happening for **left-alignment**.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue which had been fixed. That works perfectly well now and I am able to do left alignment. You can check the attached fiddle and the results.

https://jsfiddle.net/1oh3dLkg

```
new FroalaEditor('div#froala-editor', {
        toolbarInline: true,
        charCounterCount: false,
      })
```

For right -
[image]

For left-
[image]

Even if you still face the same issue, feel free to write back to me. I will be happy to assist you.

Thanks,
Gaurav